# How to simplify expression with If in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, if-statement

I need to pass a class to the table cell, if it possesses the required state.

I wrote this:

```
%td{class: (if a.state == 'accepted' then 'positive' elsif a.state == 'proposed' then 'warning' elsif a.state == 'changed' then 'warning' else 'negative' end )}
```

It works, but looks terribly. How can it be simplified? Or are there any other solutions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd make a Hash of the states, so then you could just do `%td {class: state_class[a.state]}`

Comment: @MichaelSzyndel: There are any number of perfectly valid places you could put a Hash. An instance variable, a helper, whatever. The question here was not "What are all the places I could possibly store a reference to a Hash in Ruby?", so I didn't answer that question. I don't understand why you feel that makes the answer bad.

Comment: This is a perfectly good use of a hash, and a good way of solving the problem.

Comment: I understand that OP uses Rails and there are some conventions and good practices in Rails. One of them is not to put stuff wherever/pollute scope but rather organise them more or less logically. This is perfect example of the opposite. I think important part of SO is not only giving shortest answers but also showing best practices.

Comment: @MichaelSzyndel: In a case where there were an obvious pitfall or one clear right answer, I would agree with you. But arbitrarily anointing one of many equal choices as the "best practice" is not my place, and I'm not aware of a strong Rails convention on this sort of thing.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a helper, define a method in this helper.

```
module SomeHelper
  def state_class(state)
    case state
    when 'accepted'
      'positive'
    when 'proposed'
      'warning'
    when 'changed'
      'warning'
    else 
      'negative'
    end
end
```

Then you can use this helper in td

```
%td{class: state_class(a.state)}
```

Comment: I would just add that it's a best practice to store strings like that in translations. Also changing case to hash would make perfect sense.

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
# in controller or helper

states = { accepted: 'positive', proposed:  'warning', changed: 'warning' }
@state = states[a.state.to_sym] || 'negative'

# in template
%td{class: @state}
```